# Doing postback on a select with onchange without JSON

Tags: c#, html, razor, selection

How do I create a `postback` with a `onchange` while getting the value into a `Request[]`

The code:

```
<select name="nameOnSelection" id="idOnSelection" onchange="">
    <option value="1">
        random string
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        random string
    </option>
</select>
```

Im coding in cshtml. and im not looking for JSON solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can easily find the closest `<form>` tag and submit it.

```
<select onchange="$(this).closest('form').submit();"/>
```